# Flutter - How to delay a function for some seconds

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function which returns false when the user select incorrect answer.

```
tappedbutton(int index) async {
 final userAnswer = await userAnswer();
   if (userAnswer) {
// Executing some code
}else{
ErrorSnackbar(); // This snackbar takes 2 second to close.
}
```

My objective is to delay calling the function for two seconds(user can click the button again , with no action triggering) after the user selects the wrong answer and to prevent the click immediatly. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to add an helper variable in the outer scope, that will indicate whether the user is on an answer cooldown or not.

The shortest solution will be:

```dart
var answerCooldownInProgress = false;
tappedbutton(int index) async {
  // Ignore user taps when cooldown is ongoing
  if (answerCooldownInProgress) {
    return;
  }
  final userAnswer = await userAnswer();
  if (userAnswer) {
    // ...
  } else {
    ErrorSnackbar();

    answerCooldownInProgress = true;
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    answerCooldownInProgress = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: while it may be working, the whole thing with 2 seconds delay (why 2 seconds actually?) is a workaround: instead when showing the `Snackbar` with `showSnackBar` method, returned `ScaffoldFeatureController.closed` should be used to indicate when a `SnackBar` is closed

Comment: I agree fully, but I just wanted to answer the asked question. The OP may do some refactoring later, but now he may be under a time pressure -- delivering imperfect, working code on time is better than delivering the perfect one after the deadline IMO

Answer (score 5):

In order to delay a function you can do below code or use `Timer()` class

```
tappedbutton(int index) async {
               await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
}
```

Comment: This will only delay every click handling by 2 seconds. Regardless if the user has pressed a button in the last 2 secods or not.

Answer (score 5):

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((val) {
    // Your logic here 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Future.delay` or `Timer()` class to achieve that.

Comment: `Future.delay` only delays the method by a given duration. If the user presses the button again, the function gets called again in parallel. A `Timer` runs a method by itself periodically but wouldn't react when the user presses the button.

Comment: @josxha how to use Timer and make the button unreactive for that specific seconds?

Comment: @FebinJohnson [Timer documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-async/Timer-class.html) [setState method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

Comment: @josxha for preventing user from activating the timer again you can use bool variable to check if the user clicked the button before or not.

Comment: @Shashoug but this wouldn't help with the main problem that the user should trigger the function by a click and not a periodically called function

Comment: @josxha so basically when the user doesn't clicked the button within two seconds, there's a new callback will be in place. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that your goal is to delay the function.
You're trying to find a way to let the user wait until the ErrorSnackbar is gone, right?

Try this approach. It saves the time when a button was clicked the last time and cancels every button press until 2 seconds have passed.

```dart
DateTime lastPressed = DateTime(0);

  tappedButton(int index) async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (lastPressed.difference(now).inSeconds < 2) {
      // button pressed again in under 2 seconds, cancel action
      return;
    }
    lastPressed = now;
    final userAnswer = await userAnswer();
    if (userAnswer) {
      // answer correct
    } else{
      // answer incorrect
      ErrorSnackbar();
    }
  }
```